# Virtualbox Ubuntu 16 guest, slow UI and animations

Tags: unity, 16.04, virtualbox

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 in Virtualbox. Asides from some slowness it's working fine, except for the User interface being very slow. For example, window animations do not happen, windows just pop up, or transparency or blur. This isn't a huge issue, but being used to the smoothness of Unity makes this quite a jarring experience.

Is this just a fact of it being on a virtual machine, or can it be fixed?

Comment: It can be fixed. Shutdown your VM. Go to settings and set your CPU count = 2, video memory =128K, system memory = 2048, 3D accel = on, and it should fly. Let me know. Cheers, Al

Comment: Install a 2D desktop environment, such as LXDE.

Comment: What is the specs of your server and how much resources you allocated to the VM?

Answer (score 0):

You may also try to enable 3d acceleration in VirtualBox

Select your VM on the LHS Settings -> Display - > Video tab, "Enable Features:" and check the Enable 3D Acceleration box Click OK

You may try to adjust video memory see the image with the settings below

https://nautilusmode.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/11_virtualbox_tutorial_settings_display_screen.png

Answer (score 0):

Apart from enabling '3D' support in VirtualBox I also ran the following command.

```
sudo bash -c 'echo vboxvideo >> /etc/modules'
```